# . C Programming - Sending a signal through a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, signals

Basically, I have a bunch of clients connected to a server. I want there to be an immediate shut down on the client's side if the server is disconnected via (Ctr C signal). Unless there is a different way, is there a way to send a signal through a socket (so my signal handler on server side would include sending a signal to its connect clients as well).

TCP Sockets, on a linux machine, writing in C code

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What kind of socket are you using? Is this TCP?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect server side socket shutdown on client program, you can use any event listener mechanisms like epoll(), select() etc in client side. If server closes TCP connection, then epoll() in the client notifies the event by `EPOLLHUP`, `EPOLLRDHUP`, `EPOLLERR` events.